# Asp Zero how to add DropDownlist to Users page?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I'm new to Asp Zero and i want to know how to add Dropdownlist and fill it from Lookups table
My objective is that i have Departments and each departments will have some their documents archived on the system only one Main Department can view, edit , or add the documents. Other Departments view only the documents related to their departments so want link the Users to the departments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Morgan,

You can follow this steps,

The first thing you need to do, is to add the relationship between `User` and `Department`

Go to `YourProject.Core\Authotization\Users\User.cs` and add to this class the `DepartmentId` like this.

```
public class User : AbpUser<User>
{
    public virtual Guid? ProfilePictureId { get; set; }

    public virtual bool ShouldChangePasswordOnNextLogin { get; set; }
    // Others propierties...

    public int? DepartmendId {get;set;}
    public virtual Department Department {get;set;}
}
```

The go to `YourProject.Application.Shared\Authorization\Users\Dto\UserEditDto.cs`

```
public class UserEditDto : IPassivable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set null to create a new user. Set user's Id to update a user
    /// </summary>
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxNameLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(AbpUserBase.MaxSurnameLength)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    // Other Properties...
    public int DepartmentId {get; set;}
}
```

After this create a new `migration` and `update` the database also you need to run `refresh.bat` file in angular project (`Angular\nswag\refresh.bat`) remember that Api must be running before running the `.bat` file.

After this, you can call `DepartmentServiceProxy` in `app\users\create-or-edit-user-modal.component.ts` to fill the DropDownList.

Then when you save the user you can select the department.

Comment: Thank you for answering me i'm sorry i didn't mention that my project not angular, it's a Web MVC so if you can guide me if that answer is the same or there is something different